# Unable to return node element by function call

Tags: javascript, dom

```
function createContent() {
  const mainContent = document.querySelector("#content");
  return mainContent;
}
```

```
function renderSite() {
  createContent();
  mainContent.appendChild(createHeader());
  mainContent.appendChild(createMain());
}
```

Whenever I run renderSite, I get an error telling me mainContent is not defined. I can fix this by adding mainContent manually to renderSite. But why am I unable to return mainContent when calliing createContent() from renderSite()?

Comment: You throw away the value returned by `createContent`, perhaps consider saving it to a variable, like `const mainContent = createContent()`.

Comment: I understood my mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mainContent` is in the `createContent()` function scope. If you want to use it this way, you need not just to run it, but assign the result of function execution like that:

```
function renderSite() {
  const mainContent = createContent();
  mainContent.appendChild(createHeader());
  mainContent.appendChild(createMain());
}
```